# an Abelian complex statistical phase from exchanging non-Abelian anyons?

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order, spin-statistics, anyons, wilson-loop

We have some discussions in Phys.SE. about the [braiding statistics of anyons from a Non-Abelian Chern-Simon theory, or non-Abelian anyons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90257/braiding-statistics-of-anyons-from-a-non-abelian-chern-simon-theory) in general.

May I ask: **under what (physical or mathematical) conditions, when we exchange non-Abelian anyons** in 2+1D, or full winding a non-Abelian anyon to another sets of non-Abelian anyons of a system, **the full wave function of the system only obtain a complex phase, i.e. only $\exp[i\theta]$ gained** (instead of a braiding matrix)?

Your answer on the conditions can be freely formulated in either physical or mathematical statements. This may be a pretty silly question, but I wonder whether this conditions have any significant meaning... Could this have anyon-basis dependence or anyon-basis independence. Or is there a **subset** or **subgroup** or **sub-category** concept inside the full sets of anyons implied by the conditions.

Answer (score 3):

If you put a non-Abelian anyon and its anti particle on a sphere, then moving
the non-Abelian anyon around its anti particle only induces an Abelian phase.

Also, twisting a  non-Abelian anyon by 360$^\circ$  only induces an Abelian phase as well, which define the (fractional) spin of the non-Abelian anyon.